# Unresolved Reference: FirebaseVisionLabelDetectorOptions, FirebaseVisionCloudLabel

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-mlkit

I've been using Firebase ML Kit to do some Image Labeling in my app. Everything worked fine, but today after updating my gradle dependencies I can no longer use some classes like `FirebaseVisionLabelDetectorOptions` and `FirebaseVisionCloudLabel`. They are highlighted in red and when I hover the mouse, I see the following message:

> Unresolved Reference: FirebaseVisionLabelDetectorOptions

Here's my code:

```
class ImageActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    // ... omited code for brevity

    private fun labelImages(image: FirebaseVisionImage) {

        val detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance()
                .visionLabelDetector

        val result = detector.detectInImage(image)
                .addOnSuccessListener { labels ->
                    for (label in labels) {
                        val text = label.label
                        val entityId = label.entityId
                        val confidence = label.confidence
                    }
                }
    }

    private fun labelImagesCloud(image: FirebaseVisionImage) {
        val options = FirebaseVisionCloudDetectorOptions.Builder()
                .setModelType(FirebaseVisionCloudDetectorOptions.LATEST_MODEL)
                .setMaxResults(30)
                .build()

        val detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance()
                .visionCloudLabelDetector

        val result = detector.detectInImage(image)
                .addOnSuccessListener(
                        object : OnSuccessListener<List<FirebaseVisionCloudLabel>> {
                            override fun onSuccess(labels: List<FirebaseVisionCloudLabel>) {
                                for (label in labels) {
                                    val text = label.label
                                    val entityId = label.entityId
                                    val confidence = label.confidence
                                }
                            }
                        })
    }
}
```

And here are my dependencies on the build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-image-label-model:17.0.2'

}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason why Android Studio can't find these classes is because they have been renamed in version 19.0.0 of the ML Kit SDK, as you can see on the updated [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/label-images).

Here's a list of changes:

**Classes**

`FirebaseVisionLabelDetectorOptions` -> `FirebaseVisionOnDeviceImageLabelerOptions`

`FirebaseVisionCloudDetectorOptions` -> `FirebaseVisionCloudImageLabelerOptions`

`FirebaseVisionLabelDetector` -> `FirebaseVisionImageLabeler`

`FirebaseVisionCloudLabelDetector` -> `FirebaseVisionImageLabeler`

`FirebaseVisionLabel` -> `FirebaseVisionImageLabel`

`FirebaseVisionCloudLabel` -> `FirebaseVisionImageLabel`

**Methods**

`getVisionCloudLabelDetector()` -> `getCloudImageLabeler()`

`getVisionLabelDetector()` -> `getOnDeviceImageLabeler()`

`getLabel()` -> `getText()`

`detectInImage()` -> `processImage()`

---

So basically your code would become:

```
class ImageActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    // ... omited code for brevity

    private fun labelImages(image: FirebaseVisionImage) {
        val options = FirebaseVisionOnDeviceImageLabelerOptions.Builder()
                .setConfidenceThreshold(0.8f)
                .build()

        val detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance()
                .onDeviceImageLabeler

        val result = detector.processImage(image)
                .addOnSuccessListener { labels ->
                    for (label in labels) {
                        val text = label.text
                        val entityId = label.entityId
                        val confidence = label.confidence
                    }
                }
    }

    private fun labelImagesCloud(image: FirebaseVisionImage) {
        val options = FirebaseVisionCloudImageLabelerOptions.Builder()
                .setModelType(FirebaseVisionCloudImageLabelerOptions.LATEST_MODEL)
                .setMaxResults(30)
                .build()

        val detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance()
                .cloudImageLabeler

        val result = detector.processImage(image)
                .addOnSuccessListener(
                        object : OnSuccessListener<List<FirebaseVisionImageLabel>> {
                            override fun onSuccess(labels: List<FirebaseVisionImageLabel>) {
                                for (label in labels) {
                                    val text = label.text
                                    val entityId = label.entityId
                                    val confidence = label.confidence
                                }
                            }
                        })
    }
}
```